# Target first link in a li

Tags: jquery, css

Here's my code

```css
.menu li > a {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Un lien</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Un lien</a></li>
    <li class="has_children">
        <a href="#">un lien</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Un souslien</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Un souslien</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Un souslien</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Un souslien</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Un souslien</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I only want to color the fisrt `<a>`of `.has_children` without coloring those from the submenu.

I try something but it does not work

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.menu .has_children > a:first-child {
   color: red
}
```

targets the immediate child of `.has_children`. Here `:first-child` is optional since you have only one `a` as immediate child element of `.has_children`.

Comment: Yes it's exact ! Thanks

Comment: I've another problem, I want to target all the li who are not into the submenu. I put a class on the submenu and I write this : ul:not(.sub-menu) li {}. Unfortunately it does not work

Comment: `.menu > li` is enough

Comment: @CorentinBranquet have you solved with my last comment?